# Ошибка пр работе с объектом JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Все тот же объект JSON формата:

```
var data = {
  "categories": [{
    "name": "Мясо",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "img": "korova.png",
      "name": "Говядина",
      "price": 93.4,
      "description": "Говяжье мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "svinya.png",
      "name": "Свинина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Свинное мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "kurica.png",
      "name": "Курятина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Куриное мясо"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "img": "ovca.png",
      "name": "Баранина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Мясо барана"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Рыба",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "img": "karas.png",
      "name": "Карась",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речная рыба"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "forel.png",
      "name": "Форель",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речная, радужная"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "osetr.png",
      "name": "Осетрина",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Морская"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "img": "karp.png",
      "name": "Короп",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Речной, зеркальный"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "img": "semga.png",
      "name": "Семга",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Океаническая"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "img": "mojva.png",
      "name": "Мойва",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Свежемороженная"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Хлебо-булочные",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "img": "baton.png",
      "name": "Батон",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Нарезной"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "karavaj.png",
      "name": "Каравай",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Вкусный"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "kalach.png",
      "name": "Калач",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С кунжутом"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "img": "bulka.png",
      "name": "Булка",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С маком"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "img": "rogalik.png",
      "name": "Рогалик",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С повидлом"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Ликеро-водочные",
    "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "img": "beer.png",
      "name": "Пиво",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Светлое, пастеризованное"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "img": "vodka.png",
      "name": "Водка",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Кристально чистая"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "img": "viski.png",
      "name": "Виски",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Крепкое"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "img": "vino.png",
      "name": "Вино",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Крепленое"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "img": "kognyak.png",
      "name": "Коньяк",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Без выдержки"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "img": "rom.png",
      "name": "Ром",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "С выдержкой"
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "img": "liquer.png",
      "name": "Ликер",
      "price": 3.4,
      "description": "Сладкий"
    }]
  }]

};
```

обращаясь к products  в следующем фрагменте кода:

Вот Вся функция

```
function CreateCategory() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.categories.length; i++) {
    var perent = document.getElementsByClassName('left-sidebar');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = data.categories[i].name;
    perent[0].appendChild(div);

    div.className = "category-btn";
    div.tabIndex = "0";
    div.style.paddingRight = "5px";

    div.onclick = function() {
      var productsArray = data.categories[i].products;
      for (var j = 0; j < ActivCategory(productsArray).length; j++) {
        var mainArea = document.getElementsByClassName('main-area');
        mainArea[0].appendChild(ActivCategory(data.categories[i].products)[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Консоль выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined
```

По логике должен получится массив..

Comment: откуда берется переменная `i`? Скорее всего обработчик присваивается в цикле и обычная проблема с замыканиями

Comment: i - это итератор. Данный кусок кода находится в цикле for

Comment: Нет, в примере из кода `i` это какая-то внешняя переменная берущаяся непонятно откуда

Comment: Дело в том, что     data.categories[i].name; отрабатывает нормально, а вот с массивом сложность.

Comment: Вот Вся функция

Comment: _Дело в том, что data.categories[i].name; отрабатывает нормально_ - из-за того, что вызов находится не внутри обработчика

Comment: Так что необходимо сделать чтоб обработчик корректно работал?

Comment: В ответе по ссылке - я расписал возможные решения, самое простое - замени var в цикле, на let

Comment: Спасибо, вроде бы все пошло..